# Laravel on my remote server isn't routing properly

Tags: laravel, remote-server

I am a beginner with remote servers and building a website, so please bear with my simple questions, if they are.

So I have created a Laravel project on my remote server (by connecting to the command line via Putty and creating a new Laravel project). However it created a folder, so I had to move all of the directories inside of that folder into my main folder, via FileZilla. This is how it appears now:
[Illustration of Uploaded files through Filezilla](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SKJrk.png)

My code in Laravel was the sample one which comes up whenever you create a new project, I did not change anything.
The only problem which is appearing, is when I visit my webpage, it says that my webpage is currently unable to handle this request (HTTP ERROR 500).

When I visit my webpage/public or any other sort of link, it gives me an error: NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161 (a Laravel error)

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: For the HTTP 500 Error, you should take a look at the Error Logs of your webserver (Nginx, Apache, ...) as for the Routing Problem you might want to clear the route cache with the command `php artisan route:clear` executed in the folder of your project.

Comment: check the permissions of the laravel folder: the webserver needs to access files and write in some directories. Better if you change ownership of laravel folder to the webserver user.

Comment: Yea I feel the permissions and group is the problem, I went to my server using PUtty and used the command "ls -la" to present all the files, and instead of having 'apache' it has 'staff', I recall I saw that you had to change this. Does anyone know the command on how to change it? I am terrible with permissions, and web servers so I do not know how to do this stuff at all

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so i have to answer here.

First what kind of server are you using? Shared or Vps? if it's a shared hosting, you have to do more than just upload the files, you'll need to configure ht access too. See this video for guide: https://youtu.be/wQMZld0Iroo

For the routing issue, it means, the route you are trying to visit does not exist. Check your web.php file to be sure the route is in there. This could be a simple spelling error.

Comment: Yea, I actually ended up following that video, but it did not seem to work. I guess he's also using different software. I used putty to access the cmd of the server. When I do "ls -la" it shows me all my folders for the laravel project but instead of having "apache" it has "staff". Someone told me that that has to be changed up.